# Spring Cloud Data Flow : Sample application to have multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, multipleoutputs, multiple-input

Spring Cloud Data Flow : Sample application to have multiple inputs and outputs.

Can anyone have a sample application to demonstrate spring cloud data flow with multiple inputs and outputs support

Answer (score 0):

These [samples apps](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/main/restaurant-stream-apps) uses multiple inputs and outputs.

The code from the [acceptance tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests/blob/fa3d4ccba6c0dbfc1fffc60704ad2c0da2ed2b82/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/acceptance/test/DataFlowAT.java#L251) provides an illustration of usage.

In dataflow you start by adding only one app to dsl with one of the required properties, then on deployment, you remove any extra properties and provide all the properties to connect the various streams.

The properties refer to each app by its registered name.